# Using Fluent API entity Framework Core 2 configure many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have the following class (reduced for bevity);

```
public class Profile : AuditableEntity
{
    ...

    public int? ApprovedById { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApprovedBy { get; set; }        
}
```

Where `ApplicationUser` has no reference to the `Profile` class.

I have tried the following in my configuration;

```
        entity.HasOne(x => x.ApprovedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApprovedById)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

As the profile will be approved by a single `ApplicationUser` but a designated `ApplicationUser` will be able to approve multiple profile. (I have no need to trace this from the `ApplicationUser` perspective, hence why no reference in the `ApplicationUser` class).

However, when I try to add my migration I get the following error;

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Profile.ApprovedBy' of type 'ApplicationUser'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I would resolve it please?

Comment: From what I can tell you don't need (nor have) a many-to-many? A `Profile` has a single `ApplicationUser` reference, right? I believe it would be sufficient to add a navigation property (something like `IEnumerable<Profile> ApprovedProfiles { get; set; }` to your `ApplicationUser` class and you are set. No need for Fluent API, EF can figure it out. You say you didn't implement one on purpose, but why wouldn't you?

Comment: yes but I like to keep my classes 'clean' and use the fluentapi to setup all my relationships. I dont really want to have to extend the applicationuser class to add each time a reference the application user in another one fo my classes either. I'm sure fluent must provide a way to discribe the relationship, I'm just missing something I think from my code.

Comment: What about `entity.HasOne<ApplicationUser>().WithMany()   .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApprovedById);`?

Comment: no unfortunately the same issue.

Comment: OK. I am no EF expert. From what I gathered googling out of curiosity, it should be possible. Maybe `AuditableEntity` also has a navigation property back to ApplicationUser? I'm just guessing now.